# Efficiently render pagination data via custom layouts?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

## Current Approach

Currently I render all my pagination results in a single element using a `<table>` that has a header, body and footer structure. The rendering style is very spreadsheet like and this one element can handle paginated results for multiple controllers.

## The Problem

I need to now support configurable rendering styles for the paginated results. The two main styles are spreadsheet and [pinterest.com](http://pinterest.com) style (by pinterest I refer to vertical columns of varying lengths).

## How To Implement

I'm looking for an answer on how to implement this using CakePHP 2.2 view features. Blocks, themes, and nested views. So that as much of the code is dry, and the configured part only applies the styling that is different.

The code to render the values in each tablet cell, the record title, and details like that should all be separated from the code that renders it either as a table or pinterest (or what ever you call that style).

## Challenges

Each method in Cake seems to present limitations. What approach bests deals with the following?

- When each record is rendered, it will need different pre/post tags, and the same for each field in that record. Those tags are defined a lot by the style renderer.
- I may need to add features in the future like AJAX editing of a field value, and shouldn't need to modify the style handlers. So the style renderer should just deal with style.
- A lot of my style tags will involve `wrapping` presented data. What CakePHP method works best for that?
- What's the best way to configure this? So that the paginate element knows which style to render.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this using an unordered list of definition lists. The key to doing this whilst keeping your code DRY is to use an element. Elements are ctp files that live in the folder Views/Elements

In my index.ctp, I changed the table to a ul tag, the tr tag to an li tag, and called the element to handle rendering the dl. Use an array to pass the object and its type to the element, and the rest can be done with css

index.ctp :

```
<ul><?php
  foreach ($blobs as $blob){
   echo $this->Html->tag('li',$this->element('dl',array('blob'=>$blob,'type'=>'Blob')));
  }
?></ul>
```

dl.ctp :

```
<dl class="<?php echo $type;?>"><?php
  foreach ($blob[$type] as $key => $v){
    echo $this->Html->tag('dt',$key);
    echo $this->Html->tag('dd',$v);
  }
?></dl>
```

Comment: that's an interesting approach. I'll need to think about that as an approach. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option may be to use CSS; you'll be amazed at what you can do with it. You can even 'flip' tables from rectangular layouts to vertical layouts (as on a mobile screen, for example), which seems to be close to what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for coding solution. I use CSS extensively in the project, but when I need is beyond just restyling.